# SMPS with long connector cable

Tags: power-supply

Hi I have a [Cooler Master Elite 371](http://apac.coolermaster.com/en/product/Detail/case/mid-tower-elite-series/elite-371.html) case which has a PSU on its bottom. Recently, I have purchased a MidRange GPU due to that SMPS connector for **CPU (4-pin)** and **ATX 12V Power connector** became short to reach on its place on motherboard.

Can I extend that connectors? Or do I need to buy new ones?

If I have to buy a new SMPS, then which one ? so that I will not face this problem in the future.

I have an AUSU P8Z77M motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can find extension cables for your power supply.  Keep in mind that every additional connector between the power supply and the mainboard reduces the available power and causes a voltage drop, so if you're overclocking or have an exceptionally power-hungry system, adding an extension cable may keep things from working properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, No I have not such power hungry system.I just want to know that may it cause motherboard fauiluer due to such power drop??

Comment: It won't break your mainboard.  If the voltage drop is too much, it'll cause system instability (programs crashing at random, especially when doing CPU-intensive things) or the computer won't turn on at all.